# is it working payU payment gateway integration in mobile apps

Tags: payment-gateway, payu

i am developing on **E-commerce** app for selling physical goods. so i need one payment gateway. but my company having only PayU Payment gateway account only. my question is it working for mobile apps ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I have successfully implemented PayU in an Android app. Made an example app you can look at.

https://github.com/pjtfernandes/PayUTestApp

Answer (score 1):

PayU has there own SDK for both android and iOS. You need to get in touch with payU guys to share the SDK and documentation for integration like payumoney is private repository.

Here is the github link for payu sdk with examples. But you have to ask for the permission from payu guys.

https://github.com/orgs/payu-intrepos

Comment: This is the proper guide for integrating PayU, in all platforms. +1

Answer (score 0):

download demo project from here [github project link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/releases/tag/s4.3.6c6m1.0.4)

and change int env = PayuConstants.STAGING_ENV;

this will do for test mode for payubiz

if you want to integrate payumoney you have to get sdk from support team they are really helpful